# freemarker how to use split in string which is readed with include

Tags: freemarker

```
<#assign reasonValue="xxx.ftl">
```

and I call it like:

```
<#include "${reasonValue}">
```

and I get output like:

```
Rejected - Something
```

how can I now use split on this ouput because I would like to get just `Something` as output

I tried:

```
<#list "${reasonValue}"?split("-") as sValue>
        ${sValue}
        </#list>
```

but problem is that instead of real value i get name of ftl file...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign output of include to some variable and then use `split` on this variable.

```
<#assign xx>
  <#include reasonValue>
</#assign>

<#list xx?split("-") as sValue>
  ${sValue}
</#list>
```

If you need to show only part of the string after "-" then use `substring` and `index_of`.

```
${xx?substring(xx?index_of("-") + 2)}
```

Comment: Thank you but now I get Rejected Something, i want to print just second value like Something. Split works :D

Comment: @senzacionale: Then just use `substring`.

Comment: In 2.3.21 you could use `xx?keep_after("- ")` instead of `xx?substring(xx?index_of ...etc)` .

Comment: @Suroj Care to elaborate?

Comment: ${"Hello World"?keep_before(" ")}
${"Hello World"?keep_after(" ")}
               OR              
<#assign test = "Hello World"?split(" ")>
${test[0]}
${test[1]}